# How can I calculate Σ_{i=m}^n (m+i)^n?

Tags: haskell

I'm currently trying to calculate the following sum:

[image: Imgur]

```
sum2015 :: Integer->Integer->Integer
sum2015 m n 
 | m>n = 0
 | otherwise = (m+m)^n + sum2015 (m+1) n
```

As an example, `sum2015 0 1` should return `1`. However, it returns `2`. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You're not calculating that sum. Note that `m` in `(m + i)^n` must stay fixed, but you use a *new* `m` here:

```
 | otherwise = … + sum2015 (m+1) n
--                         ^^^^^
--                         oh oh
```

Therefore you get:

```
sum2015 0 1 
  = (0 + 0)^1 + sum2015 (0 + 1) 1
  = (0 + 0)^1 + (1 + 1)^1 + sum2015 (1 + 1) 1
  = (0 + 0)^1 + (1 + 1)^1 + 0
  =  0        + 2
  =  2
```

Instead, calculate all `(m + i)^n` and sum them afterwards:

```
sum2015 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
sum2015 m n = sum . map (\i -> (m + i) ^ n) $ [m..n]
```

Or, if you're not allowed to use that, use a worker:

```
sum2015 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
sum2015 m n = go m
   where go i = ...
```

Comment: We have not  learned to use the .map (\ i -> (m + i) ^ n) $ [m..n] yet .
How could I do differently?

Comment: @ChryssaTerizi: Sorry, my Internet doesn't work properly at the moment. You simply use another function that uses `i`. I left that part as an exercise.

Comment: @ChryssaTerizi do you know list comprehensions? `map (\i -> (m + i) ^ n) $ [m..n]` = `[(m + i) ^ n)| i<- [m..n]]`

Comment: @Franky No , we have not learned it yet . We have learned the basics.

Comment: @ChryssaTerizi You can use the worker wrapper approach as mentioned here: https://wiki.haskell.org/Worker_wrapper

Answer (score 1):

I can offer this option:

```
sum2015 m n = sum [(m + i) ** n | i <- [m..n]]
```

Firstly, I created list of numbers from m to n "[m..n]".
After for each i in this list, I computing terms of the sum.
Finally, just use "sum" function for obtained result list.
'**' - Pow function

Comment: Thanks for your help .It took me time but i solved it ! I used another function
`sum2 x y z`
`| x > y = 0`
`| otherwise = ( z + x )^ y + sum2 ( x + 1) y z` 
Essentially , I keep the variable z with value m , i call it with these values 
`sum2015 m n = sum2 m n m `
It works !

Comment: @ChryssaTerizi: Which is essentially the worker `go` ;).